# Glassfish 3.1.2 with IIS7.5 (sun-passthrough) not working for https

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl, iis-7, glassfish

I have set up a Glassfish 3.1.2 cluster with 2 local instances and deployed an application. The application is accessible from the machine for both http and https(ssl) traffic when accessing glassfish directly via ip address and not through IIS (I use the default ports 28080/81 28181/82). However when I try to access the site via IIS, it only works for http traffic and dies for https.

I have followed the oracle guide to set up IIS for use with the loadbalancer plugin. I have set up a self-signed cert and added it to IIS. I have created a loadbalancer and exported the xml config file properly. I have created the ISAPI filter and virtual directory. I know that this works because it is working for http traffic. However for some reason, whenever I try to access via https it dies.

Even for https, the ISAPI filter is actually working and attempting to handoff to glassfish because the error page is coming from the sun-passthrough virtual directory and is not the standard IIS error. The problem seems to be the handoff to the glassfish ssl listener from IIS (http-listener 2).

The lb.log has an NSS error, it says it might not be able to find the sec_db files. However those files exist and are accessible, and I also read that glassfish no longer supports NSS anyway so I am not sure that is the issue.

I can find no documentation whatsoever for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.